# Create new index based on conditional increment

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable

I have a dataframe that looks like this (but with 1000s of rows):

| Person_ID | Visit_ID | Time_Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 2 | NA |
| 3 | 3 | NA |
| 3 | 4 | 1444 |
| 4 | 5 | NA |
| 4 | 6 | 0 |
| 4 | 7 | 0 |
| 4 | 8 | 180 |
| 5 | 9 | NA |
| 6 | 10 | NA |
| 7 | 11 | NA |
| 7 | 12 | 19 |
| 8 | 13 | NA |
| 8 | 14 | 25 |
| 9 | 15 | NA |

What you see from this is that:

1. The same person_ID can be in multiple rows
2. The Visit_ID always increments by 1
3. The Time Diff is sometimes NA, sometimes negative, sometimes positive

What I want to do is to:

1. Create a new Visit_ID (Let's call it New_Visit_ID)
2. Start that ID from 1 on the first row and then increment for each row the Person_ID changes OR the Time_Diff is >24 (i.e. not NA or <=24)

What this means is that the same Person_ID with a time diff of <=24 should have the same New_Visit_ID, i.e. some kind of conditional increment.

Hope this is clear!

The desired output should be:

| Person_ID | Visit_ID | Time_Diff | New_Visit_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | NA | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | NA | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 1444 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | NA | 5 |
| 4 | 6 | 0 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 | 0 | 5 |
| 4 | 8 | 180 | 6 |
| 5 | 9 | NA | 7 |
| 6 | 10 | NA | 8 |
| 7 | 11 | NA | 9 |
| 7 | 12 | 19 | 9 |
| 8 | 13 | NA | 10 |
| 8 | 14 | 25 | 11 |
| 9 | 15 | NA | 12 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create two columns 'ind1', 'ind2' based on the two conditions 1) checking 'Time_Diff' greater than 24. 2) check whether the adjacent elements of 'Person_ID' are same, then add them together, get the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) to create the 'New_Visit_ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(ind1 = (Time_Diff > 24 & !is.na(Time_Diff)),
   ind2 = Person_ID != lag(Person_ID, default = first(Person_ID)),
   New_Visit_ID= cumsum(ind1 + ind2) + 1, ind1 = NULL, ind2 = NULL)
```

-output

```
#    Person_ID Visit_ID Time_Diff New_Visit_ID
#1          1        1        NA            1
#2          2        2        NA            2
#3          3        3        NA            3
#4          3        4      1444            4
#5          4        5        NA            5
#6          4        6         0            5
#7          4        7         0            5
#8          4        8       180            6
#9          5        9        NA            7
#10         6       10        NA            8
#11         7       11        NA            9
#12         7       12        19            9
#13         8       13        NA           10
#14         8       14        25           11
#15         9       15        NA           12
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Person_ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L), Visit_ID = 1:15, Time_Diff = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1444L, NA, 0L, 0L, 180L, NA, NA, NA, 19L, NA, 25L, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```